# Shebang #! unrecognized in Ubuntu, File created in Windows7 | Troubleshoot encoding

Tags: php, ubuntu, windows-7

Basically, the file was broken some where along the way from Windows7 to Ubuntu.

How can I look at a binary representation of the file to see what happened?

Comment: What happens when you run `./myscript.php`? What if the shebang line pointed to `/usr/bin/php5`?

Comment: Have you checked with the alternatives system what php is selected? That is `/etc/alternatives/php` will *also* be a symbolic link, and needs to point somewhere sensible. `man -k alternatives` should help.

Comment: Please note my edited question.  The symbolic linking is working.  Verified this with the "linux version" of the file.

Comment: Went back and saved all files in ASCII. This should help by eliminating the BOM and setting the Bytes / Character to 1.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

PHP command line script still have to have the `<?php`  opener in them.

```
#!/usr/bin/php
echo "hi mom!\n";
```

will not work, it has to be

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
    echo "hi mom!\n";
```

This is because there's no such thing as a "php script". There are only various text files that have PHP code blocks embedded within them. Even in CLI mode, PHP expects/requires to see at least one `<?php` block. Otherwise the interpreter won't kick in and won't see any of the code, even though you've stated it's a PHP script with the shebang.

PHP cli mode is basically a hacked-in afterthought. PHP started out as a server-side CGI script parser and has not fundamentally changed from that mode.

Comment: @Chris: You can use something like `od` to dump out the file in various representations (octal by default, but can be switched to hex with `-x` arg). The BOM shouldn't matter in a CLI php script - it only trips up web-based scripts by sending the BOM to the client which screws up header manipulation by the script.

Comment: You can also see exactly what's happening to the script execution by doing `strace ./myscript.php`. It'll dump out the full list of syscalls made while executing the script. You'd see PHP fired up in there somewhere if it is indeed getting invoked via the shebang.

Comment: Thanks Excellent info.  I verified character for character they are the same in gedit except the l and the w in the file name.  "od" showed me that 90%+ of the binary data is different (or shifted, did not check yet).  Learning how to use advanced strace options.  Thanks again for pointing me in a good direction.  Once/When I find the solution, I'll post it.

Comment: Don't forget that windows uses \r\n for line breaks, and unix uses \n. That'll shift things by one byte for every line in the script.

Comment: Run `dos2unix` on your windows files, that should fix the line ending troubles.

Answer (score 3):

Did you run with a `./`?

IE:

```
./myscript.php
```

Comment: .. and `chmod 755 myscript.php`

Comment: @klang, he stated he already made it executable. "I verified myscript.php was executable" :)

Answer (score 3):

Try opening it with vi(m) and you'll see the problem. It's a bad intepreter (^M) at the end of each line. Try converting it (fromdos or dos2unix), this shoul'd fix the problem ;-)

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that the files created on Windows have a BOM that is confusing matters.

Comment: Went back and saved all files in ASCII.  This should help by eliminating the BOM and setting the Bytes / Character to 1.

Answer (score 1):

When using Notepad++ on a Windows machine, one can change the EOL character from Windows to UNIX by going to

Edit > EOL Conversion > UNIX format

[image: EOL menu option in Notepad++]

Double-check Notepad++'s status bar at the bottom-right to confirm your selection.

[image: EOL status in Notpadd++]

After saving and running from the command line, you should find that the PHP interpreter directive is now properly recognized.