# Getting cron job error because of <?php tag

Tags: php, cron-task

I've set up a cron job to run. It executes a php file which is named cronj.php
But it doesn't work and cron job notification I get is:

```
/root/website/myworld/blabla/cronj.php: line 1: ?php: No such file or directory
```

And line 1 in that file is simply a php tag `<?php` I don't know how

Comment: Show us the entry in your crontab.

Comment: possible duplicate of [shebang #! does not work in ubuntu linux when created in Windows 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5383960/shebang-does-not-work-in-ubuntu-linux-when-created-in-windows-7)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Cron is executing the file as if it was a shell script. Normally you would put in a shebang line (like `#!/usr/bin/env php`) at the top of the file so that the shell knows how to invoke it, but PHP doesn't like it - as it outputs everything outside its tags. Thus, instead of this:

```
0     3     *     *     *         /mypath/myscript.php ...
```

try this:

```
0     3     *     *     *         /usr/bin/env php /mypath/myscript.php ...
```

or use @Ravenex's trick.

**EDIT** I was just rightly admonished for assuming PHP behaves in a consistent way. Apparently, shebang *does* work in PHP. My apologies to @chess007.

Comment: Hm, indeed, you are correct. I tested CLI with standard input, and foolishly believed it would behave the same as with a filename argument.

Comment: so no my path would look like this?: /usr/bin/env php /root/website/myworld/blabla/cronj.php

Comment: That looks correct. Or, as I have been told, you can keep your cron entry as is, and put `#!/usr/bin/env php` as the first line in your PHP script.

Comment: Ok I'll test both solutions now.

Answer (score 4):

We use cron to run nightly tasks in a php facebook game. We do it by using curl like this:

`/usr/bin/curl http://www.ourdomain.com/page.php`

If I remember right we had some issues using localhost to try to avoid external lookups. Also we tried using php command line execution, which mostly worked but caused a few strange bugs.

Comment: We also found this allows for easier debugging because it puts the script in a place where it can be tested from a browser and debug information can be readably outputted.  Though with this solution be careful to think about security so that outside users can't stumble upon and run the script.

Answer (score 1):

Try to call the web url (http://.....).

It's apparently not parsing it as an PHP script.

Edit:
Please show use the cronjob you used, to verify my hunch was right.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to set your cron and also give email address in your cron setting Cpanel so that you get an email when cron runs successfully

wget -O -  http://YOURSITE/cron.php