# Cron job report error

Tags: php, cron

I got a cron job with the following code:

```
<?php
require "config.php";
$truncate = $mysqli->query("TRUNCATE rss_feed");

$cars = $mysqli->query("SELECT *,(SELECT title FROM companies WHERE companies.company_id = cars.company_id) AS car_company,(SELECT car_model FROM models WHERE models.model_id = cars.model_id) AS car_model FROM cars, companies WHERE cars.company_id = companies.company_id AND car_active = 'Active' AND rssPost IS NULL ORDER BY datetime DESC");
$result = $cars->num_rows;

if ($result > 0) {
    while ($row_cars = $cars->fetch_array()) {
        $title = $row_cars['car_company'] . ' ' . $row_cars['car_model'] . ' ' . $row_cars['car_cc'];
        $link = '/car.php?id=' . $row_cars['car_id'];
        $description = $row_cars['car_description'];
        $datetime = $row_cars['datetime'];
        $row_car_id = $row_cars['car_id'];

        $insert = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO rss_feed (title, link, description, datetime) VALUES ('$title','$link','$description','$datetime')");
        $update = $mysqli->query("UPDATE cars SET rssPost='Yes' WHERE car_id = '$row_car_id'");

        if (!$insert) {
            printf("ERROR: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
        }
    }
    printf($result . " cars inserted");
} else {
    printf("No new cars inserted");
}
```

I've set cPanel to run the php file every 3 hours and i got he error below:

```
/public_html/system/cron_rss.php: line 1: ?php: No such file or directory
/public_html/system/cron_rss.php: line 2: require: command not found
/public_html/system/cron_rss.php: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/public_html/system/cron_rss.php: line 3: `$truncate = $mysqli->query("TRUNCATE rss_feed");'
```

If i run the file through the URL, it works ok without errors. My IDE editor confirms that there is no suspicious code. I got 755 CHMOD for the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the first error line it seems that you are not calling the script properly with cron.

Depending on your Host and your possibilities you may try one of these:

Specify the cron entry this way:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php <path_to_your_script>
```

Or specify the cron entry this way:

```
php -q <path_to_your_script>
```

Or you can try to write this in the first line of your script:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
```

You can also check if this this discussion could help:

[discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8626907/getting-cron-job-error-because-of-php-tag)

Comment: Seems like `php -q` was missing in the first place. Your answers cleared this out. I will check it in 2h that the cron will run again.

Comment: Just to confirm that, `php -q` was the problem. Everything works well. Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

Try having the cron job use wget or curl to hit the URL